# Windows batch - nested variables and delayed expansion

Tags: windows, batch-file

newbie here who would appreciate some help. I'm trying to generate to generate random file names (i.e. for each file in the source directory, a different random alphanumeric figure should be generated)

The function that generates the random alphanumeric name works but when the value is returned to the main routine, it remains the same across all the files. Not sure where the problem is but I suspect it has something to do with delayed expansion.

```
@Echo Off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

dir "D:/Source" /b > List.txt

FOR /F %%i in (List.txt) DO (

CALL:Alpha Numb
echo !Numb!
md D:\Output\%%~ni
rar a -v50M -hpabc123 -m0 -ep "D:\Output\%%~ni\!Numb!.rar" "D:\Source\%%i"

)

goto:eof

:Alpha
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set _RNDLength=40
Set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
Set _Str=%_Alphanumeric%987654321
:_LenLoop
IF NOT "%_Str:~18%"=="" SET _Str=%_Str:~9%& SET /A _Len+=9& GOTO :_LenLoop
SET _tmp=%_Str:~9,1%
SET /A _Len=_Len+_tmp
Set _count=0
SET _RndAlphaNum=
:_loop
Set /a _count+=1
SET _RND=%Random%
Set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%
SET _RndAlphaNum=!_RndAlphaNum!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
If !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop
REM Echo %_RndAlphaNum%
ENDLOCAL & SET "%~1=%_RndAlphaNum%"
Exit /b
```

Comment: Move `@echo off` and `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to the first two lines of the script; you're trying to use delayed expansion in your `rar` line before you've turned it on.

Comment: you seem to know, how to use delayed Expansion. So use it right: move the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to the beginning of your batchfile and Change `echo %Numb%` to `echo !Numb!`

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. Moving the `@echo off` and `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to the top and changing `echo %Numb%` to `echo !Numb!` almost did the trick. However, the random number generated in the second iteration was short of the required 40 characters. Added `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to the start of the function and it works perfectly (i.e. need to use delayedexpansion twice)

Comment: You should change your `FOR /F` command line to `FOR /F "eol=| delims=" %%i in (List.txt) DO (`, because the listed file names might contain *spaces* or even start with `;`; anyway, you do not need a temporary file `List.txt`, so you could combine the `dir` and `FOR` lines to `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%i in ('dir /B "D:\Source"') do (`, so the output of `dir /B` is immediately parsed by `for /F`...

Comment: Please do not edit your question and implement the solution, because then the question does not make sense anymore; better add an answer and show the resolved code there...